# Spring Boot JPA Native Query - is not null check based on parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpql

In Spring boot JPA native query how can we add a dynamic check if a column value can be null or not based on the parameter. For example, in the below scenario if `isEmailNullAllowed` is `true` than the 'email' column can be `null` else it has to be `not null`.

```
@Query(value = "select * from users where user_id=:userId and email is not null")
List<User> findByName(@Param("userId") String userId,
                      @Param("isEmailNull") Boolean isEmailNullAllowed);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `or`:

```
@Query(value = "select * from users where user_id=:userId and (:isEmailNull = true or email is not null)")
List<User> findByName(@Param("userId") String userId,
                      @Param("isEmailNull") Boolean isEmailNullAllowed);
```